# how should I shuffle a list with certain percentage?

Tags: python

I used random to shuffle a list. i need to random the sequence in a certain percentage. for example, list is [1,2,3,4,5], I shuffle the list for ten times, i want the first element is 2 with 50% percentage, second element is 1 with 30% percentage and so on.

thanks

Comment: try this http://nicky.vanforeest.com/probability/weightedRandomShuffling/weighted.html

Comment: @Lucefer, you should perhaps make an answer out of that

Answer (score 0):

Lets try this with one case: 50% chance of a number being placed at index 0:

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5]
# To store newly sorted list
result = []

#say I want a 50% chance for some number to shuffle into result[0]

#make a list that scales to 100.. im using 10 for this example.
scale = [i for i in range(10)]
print(scale)

#make a 'random' selection from this scale
placement = random.choice(scale)

# since a random choice has an equal chance of landing on either half of the scale,
# your effective probability of this happening is 50%
if placement <5:
    result.append(1)
else:
    #do something else
```

The same goes for 30%...
You will need a larger scale to account for more granular values

such as 31% or 71.6 e.g: len(scale)==100, len(scale)==1000 respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the below code:

```
>>> import random
>>> l=[1,2,3,4,5]
>>> l2=[random.sample(l,len(l)) for i in range(10)]
>>> print('\n'.join([('Index %s. %s appears %s'%(idx,max(i,key=i.count),int((max([i.count(x) for x in i])/len(i))*100)))+'%' for idx,i in enumerate(zip(*l2))]))
Index 0. 2 appears 30%
Index 1. 2 appears 30%
Index 2. 4 appears 50%
Index 3. 3 appears 30%
Index 4. 3 appears 40%
>>>
```

Comment: elegent codes，how should I modified it to make element 3 apperars at index 0 with 50% ? thx

Comment: @alextre What ya mean?